# Get pathname of from where user clicked in Next.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a button in a `<Nav/>` component that is shared between two components.
when the button is clicked it opens up a `<FileUpload/>` component.

**`<FileUpload/>` can be accessed from:**

```
<Profile /> => routes to '/profile'

<Home /> => routes to '/home'
```

inside `<FileUpload/>` is there any way to check which route the user has just come from?

so inside the `<FileUpload/>` component I can see:

`` `user has just come from ${route} route` => either /profile or /home ``

Answer (score 1):

with `useRouter` hook:

```
const router = useRouter()
console.log(router)
```

it gives you a lot of information check if your answer is in it;

Answer (score 1):

inside your FileUpload component import `useRouter` hook at the top from `next/router` then use it inside your component to get the pathname like this:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const FileUpload = ()=> {
   const router = useRouter()
   const {pathname} = router;
  
   console.log("user come from: " + pathname)

  return (...);
}
```